# in jscrollpane, scrolling is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, jscrollpane

Objective:: want to make a registration pop page with vertical scroll bar by using jScrollPane.

Issue:: vertical scrollbar is not moving

HTML code::

```
<div id="register" class="wpml-content jspScrollable" >
    <div class="jspContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 370px;">
        <div class="jspPane">
            <form action="register" method="post" id="form" class="group" name="loginform" >
              <!-- code for registration-->
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="jspVerticalBar">
            <div class="jspCap jspCapTop"></div>
            <div class="jspTrack" style="height: 200px;">
                    <div class="jspDrag" style="height: 77px; top: 0px;">
                            <div class="jspDragTop"></div>
                            <div class="jspDragBottom"></div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="jspCap jspCapBottom"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS code::

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/plugins/jScrollPane-master/script/jquery.jscrollpane.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/plugins/jScrollPane-master/script/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/plugins/jScrollPane-master/script/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/plugins/jScrollPane-master/script/mwheelIntent.js"></script>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 $('#register').jScrollPane();
});
```

CSS code::

```
.jspVerticalBar {
   width: 8px;
      background-color: #ededed;
}
.jspTrack {
   width: 8px;
   background-color: #ededed;

}
.jspDrag {
   width: 8px;
   background-color: #ccc;
}
```

I checked http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html as I am new to jScrollPane but not getting where am I missing code.

Comment: You don't need to include the JScrollPane JS twice - just use the .min file

Comment: I have removed jquery.jscrollpane.js, but still not working

Comment: I assume you're also including the jQuery library before JScrollPane? Are there any error messages in your console?

Comment: Hi, I am using jquery-1.9.1.js, and there is no error message in console

Comment: is there any css issue? vertical bar is there but not scrolling till bottom of pop page

Comment: issue is solved, it was css issue. Thanks .

Comment: Would you please share your FIX with us? *facepalm*

Comment: Hi xcy7e, it was the height issue with one of the div blocks,